# Passing value from HTML to JavaScript before the document is ready

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external JavaScript function that I need to call in each of my HTML files before the page is rendered (it's setting the locale), each time with a different argument. The script file with the function is included in the `<head>` element.

What are the way to pass an argument inside the script before the page is rendered? I'm unable to use hidden `<input>` or `<div>` then and would like to avoid embedded `<script>` calls.

Comment: Why are you unable to do that and want to avoid `script` tags? There is not really another way I think. Unless you want to use AJAX to get some stuff?

Comment: I'm unable to pass them in a hidden `<div>` or `<input>`, because there's no place to put them into - the body hasn't been rendered yet. As for the embedded function calls they don't look right to me, interfering with the division into presentational and behavioral layers. I'd like to just link the script to the HTML page and do all the logic inside of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just introduce a locale variable in the global scope, within the `<head>` section, just before your script is called, and then modify your script to look for that variable.

```
<head>
    <!-- ... -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var locale = "fr-CA";
    </script>
    <script src="/js/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

Comment: What about _like to avoid embedded <script>_?

Comment: I only wanted to avoid embedded function calls. Declaring a variable seems clean enough to me.